# Definition of parameters using the information provided by "typeid"

Tags: c++, arrays, typeid, blitz++

I've just started learning c++. I have a question that hope you could help me.
I'm working with blitz++ library and want to define an array using such a command:

```
blitz::Array<double,2> B(3,3);
```

as can be seen the array type is set to be `double`; however, this array should be defined according the type of another variable (let call it A) which might be double, int, etc. I googled and found out that I can use "typeid" for identification of types:

```
char const* A_type = typeid(A).name();
```

and now I want to define my array according to the above mentioned information (A_type), like this

```
blitz::Array<A_type,2> B(3,3);
```

but it didn't work.

Could you please give me a piece of advice how to use the information provided by A_type?

Comment: decltype  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype  ?

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, perhaps I'm using it in the wrong way:   blitz::Array<decltype(A), 2> B(3,3);     Its seems the output of both typeid and decltype are char const*; i don't know if it would be helpful or no...

Comment: What's the reason you don't know the type of `A` ? Can you show some example code that illustrates your exact situation ?

Comment: Imagine A is a kind of data which is provided by another function or any user-defined data...

Comment: @ir0098 : I can imagine many things. I'd just like to see an example of what *you* had in mind, so we can help you solve *your* issue. "Data provided by another function" and "user-defined data" would have a type which you can simply pass to `blitz::Array`.

Comment: Use typeid only if you don't know the type at compile time. What you're trying to do can be achieve by meta programming (or reflection if you have the right clang version). But if you just started learning c++, it could be hard. Go check boost hana.

Comment: In fact, it's not only the matter of learning. I'm doing image processing in c++. I read my images using ITK and then convert them to blitz++ arrays and do the processing and finally I want to convert the resulted image which is in blitz++ format to the ITK image format.